# HTML5 Form Validation Multiple checkboxes allow multiple not all

Tags: html, forms, validation

I am using HTML5 Form Validation, but I need either a fieldset or at least 1 box checked for the form to validate. but when I use the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="category" required name="category" value="Singer" class="smoothborder"> Singer (Solo)
                <input type="checkbox" id="category" required name="category" value="SingerDuo" class="smoothborder"> Singer (Duo)
                <input type="checkbox" id="category" required name="category" value="Band" class="smoothborder"> Band
```

It forces the user to select all checkboxes to validate the form, when they may only need to check 1 or 2.

If I change 'required name' to 'name' then the user is not forced to check a box, and I need at least one for the info required.

Is there a workaround for this without using javascript?

Comment: Unfortunately, you will need a help of javascript for multiple checkboxes. Besides that, I noticed that you put same id attributes for each checkbox. You should always have unique ID for each HTML element.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I give the checkboxes in a fieldset different IDs then I'll need apply a seperate validation rule for every single one. 
With the Radio buttons I have same IDs and validates perfectly.
Any idea on a working JS code for what I require?

Comment: Use same class attribute value for that. For example class="checkbox-category"
Then, instead of id, use ".checkbox-category" selector for validation

Comment: Of course: 
`<input type="checkbox" id="category-singer" name="category" value="Singer" class="category checkbox smoothborder" required> Singer (Solo)
<input type="checkbox" id="category-singerduo" name="category" value="SingerDuo" class="category checkbox smoothborder" required> Singer (Duo)
<input type="checkbox" id="category-band" name="category" value="Band" class="category checkbox smoothborder" required> Band`


Then you use ( in case of jQuery )  '.category.checkbox', instead of '#category'

Comment: @niklaz thanks for the code... since I'm not using Jquery and have no idea about JS, how do I write the script code to validate the checkboxes? and can I use the same code for multiple checkbox fieldsets?

Comment: you could use some already well written vanilla JS libraries for form validation, such as Validatinator - 
Here is example how to initialize it - 
https://github.com/JenkinsDev/Validatinator/wiki/Using-Validatinator#instantiating-a-validatinator-object 
And here how to set element to required: 
https://github.com/JenkinsDev/Validatinator/wiki/Validation-Methods#required